# Does $PV=nRT$ hold for the endpoints of an irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, reversibility

I have read the following:-

1. $PV=nRT$ holds throughout a reversible process
2. $PV=nRT$ does **not** hold throughout an irreversible process because the ideal gas law is only applicable for gases in equilibrium i.e. **not** suddenly expanding/compressing.

Now, my question is will $PV=nRT$ hold ***only*** for the initial and final states (i.e. endpoints) of an irreversible process? I feel this may be possible because the gas will be in equilibrium at the endpoints and not suddenly expanding/compressing.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: What do you mean by equilibrium? (it's actually not trivial) It doesn't even necessarily hold for the starting and final states. If you discuss not some ideal to model but real physics, then there are no closed physical systems, and there are long range correlations, thus these basic laws do not hold per se. I recommend you to look at "Tsallis equilibrium".

Comment: I agree with @Kregnach that the initial and final states of an irreversible process do not have to be equilibrium states (just take an irreversible process and cut it in several smaller processes as a proof). If we specify that the system is in equilibrium at the beginning and the end of the process, then, of course the ideal gas equation holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. The processes considered in thermodynamics are always between a starting and a final *equilibrium state*. Even if the real process may be too fast to allow the system to remain close to equilibrium states, we implicitly assume that the initial state is an equilibrium state and that after the final state has been reached, enough time to equilibrate is given to the system.